# Is value "in" some other values, in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

Coming from an extremely spoiled family upbringing (turbo pascal, python, ruby) I'm a bit puzzled when it comes to doing all the household chores myself.

Yesterday was one of these days where I just did not find myself a solution. I had to check whether a value matches one of some other values.

```
 x = some_function_return_value();
 if x in (1,4,17,29,35):
```

That's how I used to write it. Now with Objective-C I obviously can't do that. And I searched the  old google, but found no answer, and the old manual, and nothing there, so how do you do this in Objective-C, without doing something cranky like the following?

```
 if (x == 1 || x == 4 || x == 17 || x == ...) {
```

**Edited**: in this case it is an (int), I know for NSArray and NSString there are methods for this

Comment: Yeah, an NSSet is probably the closest thing -- still pretty clunky compared to the Pascal `in` (which none of the major C-based languages support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) syntax in objective C that uses "in" to loop over collections, however given it requires converting your int values to NSNumbers, it's probably easier to use C here

```
BOOL success = NO;
int size = 5
NSInteger numbers[size] = {1,4,17,29,35};

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (yourValue == numbers[i]) {
        success = YES;
        break;
    }
}

if (success) {
    /* do your stuff */
}
```

admittedly not as nice as python...

Comment: Problem with this is that the compiler can't optimize it as nicely as a `switch` or large `if`. But it sure would be faster than an `NSArray` or `NSSet` lookup.

Comment: As for the ANSWER: I chose this one, since jbat100 admitted it's not as concise as in e.g. python (and DarkDust said the same), never can be. Though he tried to solve the question with the (int) in mind. I admit: the only way I could come up with this question is due to the fact that I did not fully comprehend the nature of Objective-C. If I would have, I probably would not have run into my problem in the first place. So as it is, it seems there is no short solution. Instead, one would have to find save grounds in the heavens of proper NS Objects.

Answer (score 4):

If it's about integer values, you can use `switch`:

```
switch (x) {
    case 1:
    case 4:
    case 17:
    case 29:
    case 35:
        do_something();
        break;
}
```

Do not forget that in C/C++/Objective-C, the cases fall through to the next by default. You need to add `break;` statements to prevent that.

For non-integer values, you have to do long `if` statements with a lot of repetition as C doesn't provide syntactic sugar or features that many scripting languages have to abbreviate this.

Another way would be for example to prepare an array and then do:

```
if ([myArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:x]])
```

or even better, use an `NSSet` for that. This will work for most objects, for example it will also work with strings.

Comment: You beat me to it. One addition is that you can also use `...` to do things like `case 4 ... 8:` to include the range from 4 to 8.

Comment: I see... the switch is not shorter than the multi-comparison, and the object oriented style would go into something like this:              

NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1], .... ... nil];
if ([myArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:x]]) {

both not more concise, aren't they?

Comment: No, neither is as concise as, say, Ruby or Python in this respect. Not even close.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my silly program of the day:

```
bool int_exists_in_array(const int n, const int a[], const size_t elementCount) {
    return (0 != elementCount) &&
      (n == a[0] || int_exists_in_array(n, a + 1, elementCount - 1U));
}
```

so this:

```
if x in (1,4,17,29,35):
```

becomes:

```
const int a[] = { 1, 4, 17, 29, 35 };
if (int_exists_in_array(x, a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: how would you call this one? int_exists_in_array(const int [1,2,4,67])? maybe I can put this in a convenience helper section of the class ...

Comment: @me1974 oh, i added an example afterwards. this is c so the array's size must be managed by you. you can use the sizeof in some cases, or you must pass around an element count or a struct which represents an array.

Comment: +1, quirky ;-) Though the recursion bothers me (at least it's a tail recursion that the compiler might optimize).

Comment: @DarkDust yup - it should be tail optimized, and i did say it was silly =) it could be easily converted to a loop if recursion were an issue.

Comment: First I have to say: you guys are amazing. I live on the countryside and nobody here has any understanding what I am doing in my work. That means I never talk to any of my pals or relatives about what I am doing in my work, not once in the last 10 years. However, here I can post a question and within 10 Minutes I have 7 (or so) professionals, from all over the world, who engage in a lively discussion. In this VERY brief time we create a rich page with valuable information. Very impressing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSSet in addition with NSValue.